# IAD/ADBannerView_Deprecated.h file not found issue in adwhirl sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator, adwhirl

I have integrated adwhirl in my application, its working fine in simulator 5.0 but is shows error in simulator 6. But i fixed that issue in  simulator 6.0 by include the header file  "IAD/ADBanner_Deprecated.h" but in simulator 5.0 its showing error like file not found. please give a idea to fix this issue . here is my code.

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_6_0
#import <iAd/ADBannerView_Deprecated.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this include give you an error? What error is this giving you in the iOS 6 simulator?

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```